# Whats the difference between an ndarry to a normal array and how to convert them?

Tags: numpy, keras, tensorflow2.0

I`m getting this error

```
Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

so I just want my ndarray to get transformed into a normal array. But how can I achieve this?

Comment: Share the `code` all numpy array's are of type `numpy.ndarray` (n-dimensional array)

Comment: What do you mean by normal array?  `ndarray` is a `numpy` array.  The error indicates you are trying a `tensorflow` object.

Comment: You need to tell us something about the array that you are trying to convert to `Tensor`.  For a start, what's its `shape` and `dtype`.  The error expression would also be good, maybe even the full traceback.  This isn't a generic problem; it's most likely a problem with your data.